# Merge (concat) every N excel files into one finel using glob function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, concatenation, glob

I have a folder that contains 1220 excel files. The 1220 files are 4 parameters from 305 points for example:

```
P1-a.xlsx 
P1-b.xlsx 
P1-c.xlsx 
P1-d.xlsx 
P2-a.xlsx 
P2-b.xlsx 
P2-c.xlsx 
P2-d.xlsx 
.
.
.
P305-a.xlsx 
P305-b.xlsx 
P305-c.xlsx 
P305-d.xlsx
```

I have the code bellow to merge all of 1220 files as one dataframe (Final_df):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas
fileList=glob.glob("*.xlsx")
dfList=[]
for filename in fileList:
    print(filename)
    df = pandas.read_excel(filename, header=None)
    dfList.append(df)

Final_df=pandas.concat(dfList,axis=1)
Final_df.to_excel("Final.xlsx",index=None)
```

Can anyone suggest a way that I can concat every 4 excels so that I have 305 final excels corresponding to P1 to P305 ???

Or a code that I can group or concat every 4 excels?? which lead to the same results?

Another suggestion is that I extract every 4 columns from the Final data frame and output it as a single dataframe named from P1 to P305??

Answer (score 2):

You can group your files by prefix using `pathlib` and `itertools` module:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
from pathlib import Path

key = lambda x: x.stem.split('-')[0]
for name, files in groupby(sorted(Path('.').glob('*.xlsx'), key=key), key=key):
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, header=None) for file in files])
    df.to_excel(f"{name}.xlsx", index=None)
```

Comment: With a minor correction (from pathlib import Path) your suggestion works. Thank you very much.